# Webforms App Layout Opinions?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have a very simple webforms app that will allow field techs to order parts from the warehouse.
Essentially it work like so:

1. User selects a category from a filter dropdown, which then binds items of that category to a gridview control

   User finds an item in the gridview and inputs a desired quantity (in a text box in a template field in each row)

   User repeats 1 & 2 as needed

   User sees a summary of the complete requisition

   User confirms items and submits the requisition for processing

My no-brainer UI design so far is the generic dropdown-above-a-gridview where there's a category drop-down list that filters a gridview, like in the eye-catching asp.net ado tutorials:

http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/15fig01vb.png

Each gridview row (in my app, not in the image above) lists an item's details and can accept a quantity input in the template textbox if the user wants to requisition that item.

Given that a user will want items from different categories during a single usage session, I'm trying to figure out a good, user-friendly way to allow users to input a quantity for an item, have a warm fuzzy feeling that their input has been accepted/stored, then change the category filter (thus binding the gridview to a different set of data) and select other items from the gridview as many times as necessary before summing up their order and submitting it.

I've thought about putting another grid below the first and adding items to it dynamically as the user selects each item.  But that seems awkward.  Ditto with an unordered list or similar simple structure under the grid.

I've also thought about just storing the user's picks in view state or session state and displaying a summary on another page, kind of like a shopping cart sort of functionality.  Maybe do that and use some sort of ajaxy goodness on the main page to display something warm and fuzzy when a quantity is input?

WWYD?  What Would You Do?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly agree with your first choice: users need to see somewhere what they have chosen or they will probably keep choosing it over again thinking it failed.  Waiting to display it on a summary page shouldn't even be an option.  I don't see much wrong with binding to another grid, although a repeater is also a decent option.  Well, there are many options.  Anyway, if there  is room to do this off to one side or another - especially the left- I definitely would, rather than at the bottom.  Also, bonus points for enabling users to change the quantities (or delete all) of an item they already selected, wherever you choose to display this.

I like the idea of a search, but be careful with auto-complete.  Google style is good where it displays results below, but I've seen people develop some that are way too aggressive and love to write over what you're typing: this is awful.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because both your choices are fine - it comes down to personal preference.  The shopping cart idea is well known. But sometimes it gets old if you have to keep going back and forth between the cart and the item selection.

What's wrong with the separate grid? -That way you keep the selection list separate from the ordered items list?

Answer (score 1):

Why tie the user to selecting the correct category and then selecting the quantity and hitting a button?

Why not use some type of autocomplete search so they can type in the produce name they want?  Then a user could type "widg", get a drop town of choices, hit tab to go to a quantity field, enter a number, and then hit enter.

Display a quickie preview with the aucocomplete too, like as single row of your data.

Then throw all these into another grid at the top of the page if its a critical part of the application, maybe at the bottom if you think the actual grid results are important.

The reason I don't like category drop downs is people who are familiar with their jobs or company usually know the names and even skus numebers for what they are trying to do.  Having them select a category instead of typing just slows them down.  Also I hate running into the "which category is this?" moment.  For example, is a chicken a pet, food, livestock, or food producer?